# Type mismatch error in google line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am doing google line chart for the first time, here i am facing an error i tried so much to rectify this .

> Error: Type mismatch. Value 1,5 does not match type number in column index 0

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/seo/seo/graphData',     
    data: {website_id:website_id,keyword_id:keyword_id,fromdate:fromdate,todate:todate},
    success: function (data1) { 
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var arr2 = [];
    //data.addColumn('number', 'A');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');

    for(var i=0; i<data1.query.length; i++){
      var arr = [];

      for(var j=0; j<data1.query[i].date.length; j++)
      { 
       arr.push(data1.query[i].date[j].page);
      } 
      arr2.push([arr]);
      //data.addRow(arr2); 
      } console.table(arr2);
      //var stringData = '[["2004", 1000 , 400], ["2005", 1170, 460], ["2006", 660, 1120], ["2007",1030,540]]';
    data.addRows([arr2]);
    //console.log(arr2);

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Time'
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Popularity'
      },
      series: {
        1: {curveType: 'function'}
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

This is the code that i am working with please help me . any help is appreciable.

Comment: {"query":[{"datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00","date":[{"page":"1","datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00"},{"page":"5","datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00"}]},{"datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00","date":[{"page":"9","datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00"},{"page":"13","datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00"}]}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple problems

first, the values for `"page"` are wrapped in quotes, making them strings, instead of numbers

```
{"page":"13","datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00"}
```

use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to convert to number

```
  arr.push(parseFloat(data1.query[i].date[j].page));
```

next, there are too many arrays being added to the data table
instead, use `addRow` directly in the loop

```
for(var i=0; i<data1.query.length; i++) {
  var arr = [];

  for(var j=0; j<data1.query[i].date.length; j++) {
    arr.push(parseFloat(data1.query[i].date[j].page));
  }
  data.addRow(arr);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data1 = {"query":[{"datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00","date":[{"page":"1","datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00"},{"page":"5","datee":"2018-05-14 00:00:00"}]},{"datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00","date":[{"page":"9","datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00"},{"page":"13","datee":"2018-05-15 00:00:00"}]}]};
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');

  for(var i=0; i<data1.query.length; i++) {
    var arr = [];

    for(var j=0; j<data1.query[i].date.length; j++) {
      arr.push(parseFloat(data1.query[i].date[j].page));
    }
    data.addRow(arr);
  }

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    },
    series: {
      1: {curveType: 'function'}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```